# How can I change size of our H1 header (product description on our product page ) in Bigcommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

We wish to change to size of our H1 header (product description on our product page )
Can anyone tell me how to do this ?

Our product description H1 appears different sizes on some products, we would like to make them all the same size and small than most appear. It is the description under the zippzy logo

Can someone tell me how to set the H1

Answer (score 1):

Try going under Storefront->My Themes->Advanced->Edit theme files->assets->scss->theme.scss->at the bottom of the file add:

```
.product-details h1 {
    font-size: 28px !important;
}
```